# how to get data from post method

Tags: php, mysql

my problem is that i have two pages on first page i am giving mcq's but the name i have given the radio button is the same as in mysql table index id so how can i recieve the posted value on the other page my code is as folllows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mcq ORDER BY RAND()",$connection);
if(!$result)
{die("could not query".mysql_error());}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<form action=\"grade.php\" method=\"post\">";
    echo "question number is : {$row['id']}<br>{$row['ques']}<br>";
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"{$row['id']}\"                   value={$row['op-a']}>{$row['op-a']}<br>";
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"{$row['id']}\"
    value={$row['op-b']}>{$row['op-b']}<br>";
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"{$row['id']}\"
    value={$row['op-c']}>{$row['op-c']}<br>";
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"{$row['id']}\"
    value={$row['op-d']}>{$row['op-d']}<br>";
    }
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"next\"><br>";
    echo "</form>";
```

and on the second page i am recieving it like this but it does not working ..

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mcq ",$connection);
if(!$result)
{die("could not query".mysql_error());}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
echo $_POST['{$row["id"]}'];
    }
```

Comment: try this `echo $_POST[$row["id"]];` single quote will just print {$row["id"]} as string

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate $row['id'] separately and use some intuition to match them up because once the html page is rendered, the string '{$row["id"]}' is replace with a value.

So try:

```
echo $_POST['{'.$row["id"].'}']
```

then tune it up to your liking.